# Rails: horizontally inline values from the ratyrate gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the `ratyrate gem` on my app and in order rate some items on my app. The following code shows the stars along with the avg rate number:

```
<p style="font-size: 17px; display: inline-block;"><%= rating_for item, 'quality', :style=>"text-align: right;" %>
 <strong style="color: #7f7f7f"><%= item.average("quality").nil? ? '0' : (item.average("quality").avg).round(2) %></strong></p>
```

As you can see I wraped everything with a basic `<p style="font-size: 17px; display: inline-block;"></p>` in order to inline the stars and the number, but for some reason they don't. I also tried a few other ways but without any luck.

Any ideas on how to inline both of them?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I added to different `div`'s and styled them with `float:left;`

```
<div style="float:left;"><%= rating_for item, 'quality' %></div>
<div style="float:left; margin-top: 1px;"><strong style="color: #7f7f7f"><%= item.average("quality").nil? ? '0' : (item.average("quality").avg).round(2) %></strong></div>
```